# how to checked pre selected checkbox in vue

Tags: html, sql, laravel, vue.js

[image]

I have a tree view checkbox and if you edit this data while selected zone and there countries must be checked true based on the previous selection, selection data countries id come from DB (obj, obj) this way so while edit same record I want that countries should check true with zone name how to archive this functionality in Vue I'm stuck here and need a solution as soon as possible.

my child checkbox code where `v-model` does not help me to check countries and zone check box where `v-model.countries.id` match with `children.id`.

my code like this:

```html
<li
  v-for="(item, i) in groupedzone"
  :key="i"
  :class=" {active: i === isexpand}"
>
  <i class="fa fa-plus" @click="togglelist(i)"></i>

  <div class="">
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      :name="item[0].country_zone.zone_name"
      v-model="isCheckboxSelected"
      v-on:change="parentChange(item)"
    />
    <label :for="item[0].country_zone.zone_name"
      >{{item[0].country_zone.zone_name}}</label
    >
  </div>
  <ol v-if="item.length != 0" class="dd-list-subitems">
    <li v-for="children in item" :key="children.id">
      <div class="">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          :name="children.name"
          :value="children.id"
          v-model="project.countries"
          :class="'zone'+item[0].country_zone.id"
        />&nbsp;
        <label :for="children.id">{{children.name}}</label>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</li>
```

Comment: Please can you share the code? Also, is there anything you've tried so far?

Comment: yes you can check now i shared code

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have the following code:

```
data: () => ({
   countries: [] // contains ids of countries that should be checked on page load
  allCountries: [] // countries array/objects 
})
```

Then in your loop:

```
<v-list-item v-for="c in countries">
    <template v-slot:default="{ active }">
       <v-list-item-action>
           <v-checkbox v-model="allCountries"
              :input-value="active"
               color="primary"
               :value="c.id"
            ></v-checkbox>
         </v-list-item-action>

          <v-list-item-content>
             <v-list-item-title>{{ c.name }}</v-list-item-title>
             </v-list-item-content>
         </template>
       </v-list-item>
```

Pay attention to

```
:value="c.id"
```

As it will result in checkbox being marked or not